# use "tee" command to append asterisk debug information to file

Tags: special-characters, asterisk, tee

When I run:

```
$ asterisk -rvvv | tee temp-log-asterisk.txt
$ ubuntu*CLI> dialplan reload
$ exit
```

this is the real output of asterisk:
[image]

**Now when I look into the content of `temp-log-asterisk.txt` I expect to see the same content but I see this instead!:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the `-n` option ("-n:Disable ANSI colour support" from [Asterisk options - Connecting to a running Asterisk](https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+options)?

Comment: I just tried the -n option (`asterisk -rnvvv`) and that still shows weird characters. That was a good one. I think the solution is something like that

Comment: Does it still show *all* the weird characters with `-n`, or just the ones like `^M`? the latter are likely carriage returns

Comment: You are right only the ones with `^M` so it fixes it a little bit more! But it still shows a lot of `^M`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting. https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I tried that but it prints on a single line because it contains -- at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @TonoNam good, that illustrates part of the problem even better, I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "weird characters" in your sample appear to fall into two categories:

1. ANSI color sequences
2. `^M` sequences, representing carriage returns (suggesting the application uses DOS-style CRLF line endings).

According to [Asterisk options - Connecting to a running Asterisk](https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+options) there is a `-n` command line option to suppress the former:

> -n:Disable ANSI colour support

There doesn't appear to be an option to specify Unix-style LF line endings, however you should be able to pipe the output through any one of the many "DOS to Unix" commands such as `tr -d '\r'` i.e.

```
asterisk -rnvvv | tr -d '\r' | tee temp-log-asterisk.txt
```

Note that this will remove colors from the on-screen output as well.